# $L_p$ space inclusion for Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

The integral here is defined in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense, the interval $[a,b]$ contains $\psi$'s support, and $\alpha<1$. $X$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous.

\begin{align*}  \left|\int_a^b \psi(v)\mathrm{d}X(v)\right|&\leq \|\psi\|_{\infty}\lim\limits_{\left|\mathcal{P}\subseteq{[a,b]}\right|\to 0}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left|X(v_{i+1})-X(v_i)\right|\\
&\leq \|\psi\|_{\infty}\mu([a,b])^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}}\lim\limits_{\left|\mathcal{P}\subseteq [a,b]\right|\to 0}\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left|X(v_{i+1})-X(v_i)\right|^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^{\alpha},
\end{align*}

where $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure. Have I correctly used the result that, for $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$, where $A$ is a finite measure space and $f$ is measurable (with measure $\mu$),we have
$$\|f\|_p\leq \mu(A)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}\|f\|_q$$
?

Comment: Where did $n$ go in $\sum_{I=0}^{n}1^{...}$?

Comment: $n$ is just the number of points in the partition $\mathcal{P}$. I've added that the norm of the partition goes to $0$

Comment: Does the missing $n$ affect the limit?

Comment: @TrialAndError by sending the norm of the partition to $0$, doesn't that send $n$ to $\infty$?

Comment: I'm asking to make sure you have thoroughly considered the terms that seem to be absent.

Comment: @TrialAndError Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Do I need to justify that that sum is finite?

Comment: I don't see how you're justifying what you have between the second and third line of your first long inequality. Don't omit steps there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57037/discussion-between-man-in-green-shirt-and-trialanderror).

Comment: I don't like chat. You can't see the Math.

Comment: @TrialAndError ok, no problem. I'm trying to use the inequality I quoted below, with $q=\frac{1}{\alpha}$, $p=1$ and $A=[a,b]$

Comment: The notation is stange to me. What's the variable of integration in the first integral? Is $X_t$ an increasing function? What does $[a,b]$ to a power mean?

Comment: @zhw I've edited the question is it clearer now? $X_t$ isn't known to be increasing

Comment: I still don't get it. The variable of integration is $v.$ what is the variable $t?$

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I was getting lost in my notation too. Does it make sense now?

Comment: OK, but if $X$ is not increasing, then why is the sum in the second line positive?

Comment: @zhw you're right, it's not - I've carried through the absolute value from the line above

Comment: That can't be right. If $X(t)= |t|$ on $[-1,1],$ then the first sum is always  $0.$ You may want to move the absolute values inside the sum.

Comment: My final question, I hope: Why do you have $$\lim\limits_{\left|\mathcal{P}\right|\to 0}\sup\limits_{\mathcal{P}\subseteq [a,b]}$$What sense does the limit make if you've already taken the $\sup$ over all $P.$

Comment: @zhw. again, thanks for asking all these questions, I realise I hadn't thought about this enough before asking. I've removed the supremum, all I need (as far as I understand) is the limit

Comment: OK, you probably meant $$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{|P|< \delta}$$ where  $P= \{ v_0, \dots, v_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b].$ Seems to me your sums should be over $i=1,2\dots,n.$ Also your first inequality can't be right, because $\int_a^b dX(v) = 0$ is possible. You might want to just omit it.

Comment: @zhw. why should the index $i$ start at $1$? As it is, $v_i$ will start at $v_0$, which is what we want. Anyway, I've removed that first inequality, although from the answer below, it looks like achieving such might not be possible anyway

Comment: What would $v_{n+1}$ be?

Comment: @zhw. ok yeah, the top limit of the sum should be $n-1$ then

Comment: @zhw. essentially, what I would have liked to do, was to bound that integral in terms of $\psi$ and the $\frac{1}{\alpha}$-variation of $X$

Comment: Right and I'll write some kind of answer to that. It seemed worthwhile to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand you are claiming that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n |a_i| \leq c\left( \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|^{1/\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} \tag{1}$$

for some absolute constant $c=c(\alpha)$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. If we choose $a_i := 1$ for all $i=0,\ldots,n$, this would imply

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i| \leq c \left( \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|^{1/\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} = c n^{\alpha};$$

hence,

$$c \geq n^{1-\alpha} \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} \infty.$$

This shows that there cannot exist a constant $c=c(\alpha)$ such that $(1)$ holds for any sequence $(a_i)_{i=0,\ldots,n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This, in turn, means that your reasoning doesn't work since the third "$\leq$" doesn't hold true.

**Remark:** The reason why $(1)$ does not hold true is that $n$ can become arbitrary large. In fact, Jensen's inequality shows that there exists a constant $c=c(\alpha,n)$ such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n |a_i| \leq c \left( \sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|^{1/\alpha} \right)^{\alpha}$$

for any $(a_i)_{i=0,\ldots,n}$. As the example in the first part of my answer shows, the constant $c=c(n,\alpha)$ explodes if we let $n \to \infty$.

**Example** Consider $[a,b] := [0,1]$ and the deterministic process $X_t := t$. If we set $t_i := i/n$ for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then

$$X_b-X_a = 1 = \sum_{i=0}^n (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})$$ and

$$\left( \sum_{i=0}^n |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}|^{1/\alpha} \right)^{\alpha} = n^{\alpha-1} \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0$$

and therefore there cannot exist a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\left| \int_a^b dX_t \right| = |X_b-X_a| \leq c \left( \sum_{i=0}^n |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}|^{1/\alpha} \right)^{\alpha}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So even in this very simple setting we cannot expect that we can bound $\left\|\int_a^b \psi(t) \, dX_t \right\|_{\infty}$ by the $1/\alpha$-variation of $(X_t)_t$.

Comment: in order for $a_i=X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_{i}}$ to be equal to some $k$ for each $i$, wouldn't the function $X_t$ have to be infinitely steep? Is there a way to use the fact that I'm only considering the function in some bounded interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt You didn't mention any assumptions on boundedness in your question (it really helps very much if you state clearly at the beginning of your question what objects you are dealing with and what assumptions you have... here, it is not even clear whether $X_t$ is a stochastic process or just a deterministic function). However, boundedness does not help, see my edited answer. Do you need the estimate only pointwise (i.e. with some constant which possibly depends on $\omega \in \Omega$) or global?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to bound $\|\int_a^b\psi\mathrm{d}X_t\|$, where $\psi$ vanishes outside of $[a,b]$. I would like this bound to contain the $\frac{1}{\alpha}$-variation of $X_t$

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt I see. Do you assume that $\sup_{\omega} \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |X_t(\omega)|<\infty$? If not, what kind of assumption do you have on the boundedness of $X$?

Comment: I realise I should've mentioned this straight away, but I'm assuming it's $\alpha$-Hölder continuous

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt That's not of any help, unfortunately... see the (counter)example in the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i well understand your last comment, i will give an answer using basic propriety of Riemann-Stieltjes integral :
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\int_{a}^{b} \varphi(t) dX_t(t)  \right|&=& \left|\int_{a}^{b} X_t(t) d\varphi(t)  \right| \rm{ because }\,  \varphi \,\rm{ vanish\,  in } \, a \, \rm{ and }\, b.\\
&\leq & \int_{a}^{b}\left| X_t(t)\right| |d\varphi(t)|\\
&\leq& c \left( \int_{a}^{b}\left| X_t(t)\right|^{1/\alpha} |d\varphi(t)| \right)^\alpha
\end{eqnarray}
Where $c=\left(\int_a^b |d\varphi(t)|\right)^{1-\alpha}$